# Optimizing Materialized View

Tags: oracle, optimization, materialized-views

Does anyone have the best way to optimize an materilaized view drawing from a View in a database on a monthly basis. I have used the "standard" but are there any other bells and whistles that could provide quick and efficent Views of refreshing data and reducing query time?

Thanks in advance.

```
MATERIALIZED VIEW Table_X 
REFRESH
  FAST
  START WITH SYSDATE
  NEXT DATE '2016-01-01' + 31
  WITH PRIMARY KEY
  As <Query>
```

Comment: Are you trying to optimize queries against the materialized view?  Or optimize the refreshing of the materialized view?  Your `next date` doesn't make a lot of sense so I'm guessing that's not what you really have.  Is the materialized view actually fast refreshable?  Is the volume of changes small enough over a month that it actually makes sense to do an incremental refresh rather than a full refresh?

Comment: I am trying to optimize the refreshing of the materialized view. The materialized view will be summary rollups. The next date is probably wrong.I would gather the volume changes to be semi incrimental at least with additional monthly rows added. What would the speed difference be between the incremental and full? Thanks.

Comment: Just like doing a full scan of a table is more efficient than using an index if you're retrieving a large fraction of the rows in the table, if the volume of change logs that accumulate over the course of a month is large compared to the number of rows in the table, a full refresh may be more efficient.  Beyond that, we'd need more details.  Is the query hitting a partitioned table where only the most recent partition or two has changed data?  If so, you probably want to use partition change tracking for example.

Comment: Are these refreshes based on conventional DML on the tables, direct path inserts only, partition DDL, or a combination of them?

Comment: Given the most recent information ( ie 6 months and sooner ) will have the greatest variance of data changes I can use a range partition for monthly or quarterly data .   A little more background: its a view of 3 aggregate Unions and 2 left joins that will aggregate monthly data which in turn will then be accessed by the materialized view to Rollup into summary tables.

Comment: What kind of data changes are they? Inserts? Updates? Deletes?

Comment: The tables I am drawing from for the Aggregate View will have inserts to them. Adding a monthly data.

Comment: Only inserts? And via conventional or direct path?

Answer (score 1):

Refresh of a materialized view, whether fast or complete, is just as amenable to performance tuning as any other operation, and generally by just about the same methods.

A refresh is just an encapsulation of various queries against the base tables, materialized view logs, the materialized view, and system tables, and all you need is insight into the complete process. It's important to realise that everything is just SQL, and that means you can add indexes, modify memomry allocations, use partitioning, and just about every other procedure

The best mechanisms for getting insight are Oracle own tools, such as AWR or event tracing. I've used both, but the latter is very insightful and will give you precise information on where the refresh time is being spent. When you see the SQL itself by using event tracing, you can probably work out where any missing indexes etc are. Look out for the potential to index on Sys_Op_Map_Nonnull(column_name).

So, having said that the techniques are all pretty standard, here are some links with info too long/specific too include here.

https://oraclesponge.wordpress.com/2006/04/12/a-quick-materialized-view-performance-note/
http://oraclesponge.blogspot.co.uk/2005/09/optimizing-materialized-views-part-i.html
http://oraclesponge.blogspot.co.uk/2005/09/optimizing-materialized-views-part-ii.html
https://oraclesponge.wordpress.com/2005/11/23/optimizing-materialized-views-part-iii-manual-refresh-mechanisms/
https://oraclesponge.wordpress.com/2005/12/08/optimizing-materialized-views-part-iv-introduction-to-holap-cubes/
http://oraclesponge.blogspot.co.uk/2005/12/optimizing-materialized-views-part-v.html

Comment: Looking to partition the materialized view instead of the aggregate view.